# PS3 Slim stuck on "Connect the controller using USB cable, then press PS button" screen

Tags: ps3

I've just purchased a PS3 slim 320GB knowing it was faulty and fancied a challenge but have got nowhere! The previous owner says their son turned the power off during an update and since then hasn't worked. I've tried re-setting the official controller, trying different leads and sockets, I've now re-formatted the hard drive using my PC but still the black screen of death wont go away. I've tried looking on various forums but still no luck.

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple.

Just connect your controller to the console with a USB cable.
Once the console detects the controller, it will move to the next screen, which is the software installation.
Keep a pen drive loaded with the latest PS3 console software. Insert the same in the USB slot.
Now just follow the on-screen instructions to install & load the PS3 console.

Answer (score 0):

I had to take out the hard drive, turn on my ps3, then turn it back off, put the hard drive back in, turn it back on and it worked perfectly. Controller reconnected and everything

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while trying to install a new hard drive. My 3rd party controller wasn't able to get past this screen, but I ordered a different one ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073CLJH8J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073CLJH8J)) and was able to get paste this screen and format my drive successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The USB cable you are using is probably not correct. Use the supplied USB cable that came with the PS3 as it supports data transfer, otherwise you will just have a controller with flashing lights.